# Google Maps Looks Grey in a hidden div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, resize

I've a problem with a Google Maps inside a hidden div. It appears complete grey, but if I resize the Webpage look good again.

This is the code that I've.

```
function initMap() {
                                        var mapOptions = {
                                            center: {lat: 20.291, lng: 153.027},
                                            zoom: 6
                                        };

                                        //var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google_map'),mapOptions);

                                        var map = new google.maps.Map($("#google_map")[0], mapOptions);

                                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                                        var lineSymbol = {
                                            path: 'M362.985,430.724l-10.248,51.234l62.332,57.969l-3.293,26.145 l-71.345-23.599l-2.001,13.069l-2.057-13.529l-71.278,22.928l-5.762-23.984l64.097-59.271l-8.913-51.359l0.858-114.43 l-21.945-11.338l-189.358,88.76l-1.18-32.262l213.344-180.08l0.875-107.436l7.973-32.005l7.642-12.054l7.377-3.958l9.238,3.65 l6.367,14.925l7.369,30.363v106.375l211.592,182.082l-1.496,32.247l-188.479-90.61l-21.616,10.087l-0.094,115.684',
                                            scale: 0.0433,
                                            fillColor: '#FFF',
                                            fillOpacity: 1,
                                            anchor: new google.maps.Point(300, 300)
                                        };

                                        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                                                map: map,
                                                icon: 'https://www.prueba.com/imagenes/icons/airport.png'
                                            });

                                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                                                return function () {
                                                    //document.getElementById("left_window").innerHTML = locations[i][3] + " ICAO: " + locations[i][0];
                                                    infowindow.setContent('<div id="content">'+
                                                                          '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                                                                          '</div>'+
                                                                          '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+ locations[i][3] + '</h1>'+
                                                                          '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                                                                          '<p><b>AD salida:</b> aerodromo salida, <b>Elev:</b> x pies<br>' +
                                                                          '<b>AD llegada:</b> ad llegada<br>'+
                                                                          '<b>Duración:</b> duracion<br>'+
                                                                          '<b>Distancia:</b> distancia<br>'+
                                                                          '<b>Max level:</b> pies'+
                                                                          '</div></div>');
                                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                                }
                                            })(marker, i));
                                        }

                                        // Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
                                        var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                            path: [{lat: 41.297445, lng: 2.0832941}, {lat: 39.5517, lng: 2.736164899999949}],
                                            icons: [{
                                                icon: lineSymbol,
                                                offset: '50%'
                                            }],
                                            map: map
                                        });

                                        animateCircle(line);

                                    }

                                  // Use the DOM setInterval() function to change the offset of the symbol
                                  // at fixed intervals.
                                    function animateCircle(line) {
                                          var count = 0;
                                          window.setInterval(function() {
                                            count = (count + 1) % 200;

                                            var icons = line.get('icons');
                                            icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
                                            line.set('icons', icons);
                                        }, 50);
                                    }
```

I don't know where is the problem, after checking all the code stills the same. I try also de Timeout.

Thanks in advance for the help or suggestions.

Comment: This is the normal google maps behavior  .. the maps in hidden div are not showed  (only grey backgroup)  .. you must reinit your map when you show the div

Answer (score 0):

CSS visibility:hidden should work display:none won't. If you don't want to see the div until it's ready then you can use offset top to hide it behind something else.